# Find k smallest pairs in two lists

Tags: python

My goal is to:

1. pair the elements in two lists; and
2. find the `k` smallest pairs.

At the moment I can pair every element in both lists with the code below:

```
import itertools  

a = [1, 3, 5, 7]
b = [2, 4, 6, 8]
c = list(itertools.product(a, b))

print c
```

And my output is:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 8), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 6), (3, 8), (5, 2), (5, 4), (5, 6), (5, 8), (7, 2), (7, 4), (7, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Suppose I set `k = 3`, it should return me the three smallest pairs: `(1, 2)`, `(1, 4)` and `(3, 2)`. How do I do that?

Comment: `sorted(c, key=sum)[:k]` (i.e. *"create a new list by sorting the original list by the `sum` of each element, then take a slice of the first `k` elements"*)?

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion works.

Comment: There are plenty of edge cases, though - for example, how do you want to deal with ties? `sorted` is stable, so items that tie will be output in the order they originally appeared, but that may not be what you want.

Comment: I haven't thought about setting a constraint to deal with ties yet. `sorted` and `heapq` output the tie in the order they originally appeared ie. `(1,4)` gets selected over `(3,2)` if I set `k=2`, and I will carefully think about what if I want to output the latter instead. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `heapq.nsmallest` with `sum` as its key function :

```
>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.nsmallest(3,c,key=sum)
[(1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 2)]
```

Or as @jonrsharpe said in comment you can use `sorted` :

```
sorted(c, key=sum)[:k]
```